# visual studio or atom with Symfony : go to definition | declaration

Tags: visual-studio, symfony, ide, atom-editor

I'm working with Symfony3 and I opened the project in my two best IDE **visual studio code** & **atom** but I don't find the behaviour that I expect to have which is **go to declaration|defintion** when maintaining <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + clicking for exemple here on "render" it must navigate to the render definition in the ControllerClass

## Default Controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir')).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried recommended plugin for atom but I find that it is an issue not resolved yet.

Can someone tell us what IDE to use and which plugin to install with Symfony knowing that this behavior is unavoidable for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall NetBeans has such functionality, but as I am testing it right now it sometimes work and sometimes not, can't say why cause for a long time I was using Atom. Another option would be PHPStorm (first and only by most PROs I know).

Answer (score 0):

Personally i use PHPStorm, when i create new project, i just enable symfony plugin for the project and it handle well.
PS : the symfony plugin should be installed in PHPStorm